# python regular expression match return full sentence

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will find the word "squirrel" in a list of sentences. The expression should return a list of full sentences that contains the word "squirrel".

Sentences that contain the word "squirrel" might look like the following sentences:

> the squirrel has a long tail (.) say (.) long tail .
>   cats (a)n(d) squirrels (a)n(d) rabbits (a)n(d) bunnys (a)n(d) (.)
>   the squirrel+has a tail

The current `re` I have looks like this

```
word_only += re.findall('(.*?' + word + '?!\S)', sentence)  
word_only += re.findall('.*?' + word + '\S+', sentence)
```

But it only returns whatever is in front of the word ("squirrel") and not after it.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You will need `re.finditer` to get `match.group(0)` for each one

Answer (score 4):

There's no real need to use the regular expressions here at all.

```
#The example string:
s = '''the squirrel has a long tail (.) say (.) long tail .
cats (a)n(d) squirrels (a)n(d) rabbits (a)n(d) bunnys (a)n(d) (.)
the squirrel+has a tail'''

sentencelist = s.split(".") #split on periods
[sentence for sentence in sentencelist if sentence.find("squirrel") != -1]
#If you don't find any squirrels, hold fire!
```

On the other hand, if you have abbreviations/titles, this script will split into too many sentences. When I had to tackle a problem like this, I ended up using a regex like `\.\s+(?=[A-Z])`, and splitting on matches. This fixes abbreviations, e.g. N.A.A.C.P., but not titles, e.g. Mr. Smithers. I ended up building a dictionary of titles, and just subbing out the periods until after I finished regexing and counting. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a **list of strings each containing a single sentence**.

```
squirrel_sentences = []
for sentence in sentences:
    if re.match(word):
       squirrel_sentences.append(sentence)
```

---

If you have a **single string containing multiple sentences**, you might try the matches of this regex, which finds the spans of characters from period to period which contain `squirrel` (also supporting the first and last sentence with the `\A` and `\Z`):

```
(?:\A|(?<=.))[^.]*squirrel[^.]*(?:.|\Z)
```

Comment: If I do it this way, the sentence is broken into chars and each char is one element of the squirrel_sentences. Why